# Set SSIS/SSAS TargetServerVersion to 2017, from 2012 - going around in circles

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017, ssdt-bi

I'm working on a SSIS solution with multiple projects.  I'm testing a migration to our new SQL Server 2017.   We've used SQL Server 2012 for a while now.

I've changed the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2017, and deployed and run the project.  But everytime I start Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2017) I get the following prompt for each project.

[image: Visual Studio wants to change the TargetServerVersion in each project, but it's already done]

It's truly insane costing a lot of time when I start Visual Studio, plus making version control messy - it writes a new DTS:VersionGUID element to each file everytime I open the solution.

In addition, each conmgr has something to say about the upgrade too, with a prompt like...

[image: Conmgr's all want to make adjustments outside the IDE, and need reloading]

Does anyone know how I can get myself out of this loop ?

Answer (score 3):

Seems I've solved the problem by finding rogue project configurations.

I used grepWin to search through the solution looking for references to SQLServer2012

I found at least 6 projects within the solution that still had a reference to SQLServer2012 within project based configuration profiles.  This was strange, because I removed old configurations at the solution level and only had the one Server 2017 configuration.   It seems that Visual Studio couldn't update project level configurations and through the IDE, I'm unable to remove the rogue configurations.

I solved the immediate problem by manually editing each project configuration, selecting all configurations.  This work stopped the looping I experienced when opening the solution.

[image: The trick was to select all configurations]

The true problem evolved however, and that is the solution had one Configuration (I removed all unnecessary configurations to solve this problem), yet individual projects had multiple configurations.  The project level configurations don't seem to be editable, and cannot be removed.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the solution.

I've been annoyed with this for months.

Finally I did the same you say by opening the .dtproj files in notepad and modifying manually the targetServerVersion tag and apparently does the same.

```
<TargetServerVersion>SQLServer2012</TargetServerVersion>
```

Comment: Thanks eherrero, glad it solved your problem.  Can you +1 my answer please.

Comment: I tried but I don't have enough reputation to vote yet